# Thermodynamics and ice cream

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

The outdoor temperature is about -30 -40 degree but it does not prevent me to eat ice cream. But I don't know what is the ice cream in thermodynamic point of view. It is not liquid.It is not solid. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, ice-cream is a solid, but it is filled with air bubbles. All this air that was incorporated in the ice-cream as it froze (through various industrial processes) means that the dairy product doesn't freeze as a solid, but rather a foamy delicious treat.

There are many websites explaining what it actually is, and how it is made, such as 
[this one](http://foodreference.about.com/od/traditional_foods/a/What-Is-Ice-Cream.htm).

Since the outside temperature is so high, the ice cream will eventually melt (the doom of all children), turning into a liquid, and releasing the air kept inside of it.

Comment: Adding to this — if you let ice cream in a cup melt you'll notice that it takes up less space after it's melted. This isn't because the ice cream contracts on melting, but because of the loss of the trapped air/gas.

Comment: Is $-40$ degrees high temperature?! I'd not call $40$ kelvins below water freezing point really high temperature.